# Firefox overflow-y in a absolute positioned div

Tags: css, cross-browser, overflow

I have a problem to which I just cannot find a solution:

There is a difference to how scrollbars are working in FireFox(69.0.3) and Chrome(77.0.3865.90).
I have a div absolute positioned containing a list of div elements. I want to be able to set a max-height to the list that can be y-scrolled.
It happens that the elements of the list contain text which should be positioned at the opposite sides of the container.

```css
.pos-absolut {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.menuList {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.elem{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
.start{
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pos-absolut">
      <div class="menuList">
        <div class="elem">
          <div class="start">Element</div>
          <div>1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
          <div class="start">Element</div>
          <div>2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
          <div class="start">Element</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
          <div class="start">ElementWithALongName</div>
          <div>4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
          <div class="start">Element</div>
          <div>5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="elem">
          <div class="start">Element</div>
          <div>6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is how the two browsers render this differently:
[image: Chrome]
[image: FireFox]

Chrome vs Firefox

The problem now is the way firefox renders the fourth element. I did not find any way to display it like in chrome. Only if I set the container not to `overflow-y:auto` but `overflow-y:scroll`. But if I do that the scrollbar will have a scrollbar in every browser in every case, which I do not want.

Does anyone have a viable solution how to render the rows like chrome does (without occluding them like in the screenshot) and without side effects (like with`overflow-y:scroll`)?

Comment: So your questions is about how to not break long lines?

Comment: I updated the question and tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.start{
  padding-right: 20px;
  width:50%;
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

Your problem is **solved** for firefox. :)

Comment: Thanks I'll take the ```width:50%``` the word-break does something I do not want, but the width does the trick, thx.